# Term for a shoe with a spring loaded spike

Tags: single-word-requests

In movies when you have a bad guy who can trigger a spring loaded metal spike from his shoe to try and hurt you, what is the metal piece and/or the shoe/boot called? There has to be a term for that, I just can't find it.

Comment: What makes you think "there has to be a term for that"? Can you back up that assumption?

Answer (score 2):

- [Shoe spike](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/film/jamesbond/9630631/James-Bond-The-best-gadgets.html)
  <sub>Source: telegraph.co.uk</sub>

> Rosa Klebb’s spiked shoes (From Russia With Love)
>   Nothing in Bond's own arsenal is quite as instantly deadly or memorable as Klebb’s poisoned shoe spikes in From Russia with Love, an accessory which helps define a whole character – even if Lotte Lenya is quite sufficiently fearsome without them.

- Poison-tipped spike

[<sub>Source Wikipedia</sub>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosa_Klebb)

[image]

---

Not to be confused with *Stiletto* which is the name of a type of heel named after a [type of knife](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiletto)

[image]

---

Nor to be confused with *spike cleats*

[image]

or *spiked shoes*

[image]
<sub>(source: [fashionghana.com](http://www.fashionghana.com/site/wp-content/uploads/shoes3.jpg))</sub>